# MFMailComposeViewController : cancel doesn't exit to my app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm trying to send a mail with MFMailComposeViewController. It happens when I click a button on my app. Of course when I click the Cancel button of the mail controller I want to go back to my app view but it doesn't work. What to do ? Here is my code :

```
MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[controller setSubject:@"Subject"];
[controller setMessageBody:@"<html>Test</html>" isHTML:YES];
[controller setToRecipients:nil];
if(controller) [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Thanks for your advices

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have you implemented this delegate method? It's called after the composer is exited by the user.

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller 
      didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
                    error:(NSError*)error 
{ 
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    return;
}
```

Comment: If that's fixed it for you then could you accept the answer? thanks.

Comment: dismissModalViewControllerAnimated 
is deprecated now, you should use
   dismissViewControllerAnimated instead