# How to send email with attachment(file PDF) in app iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have button in my app, when I open ,it shows me new email message with attachemnt. After I sent email to my e-mail address I have this message and attachment, but attachment contains last screen from my app.. I would like open this message with attachment from supporting file. Maybe you know where can I have mistake?

```
- (IBAction)showEmail:(id)sender {

NSString *emailTitle =  @"elllo";

NSString *messageBody = @"Hi ! \n Below I send you ";

NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"m1891@gmail.com"];

NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, self.view.bounds, nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[mc setSubject:emailTitle];
[mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
[mc addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"MV.pdf"];
[mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

[self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

}

Comment: [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; means that you are making a screenshot, draw the actual PDF itself

Comment: OK thank you @ogres ! How can I send email with attachment(file pdf) from supporting file ?

Comment: You can first read file as NSData and then attach that data

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Below it's correct sollution:

```
 - (IBAction)showEmail:(id)sender {

    NSString *emailTitle =  @"elllo";

    NSString *messageBody = @"Hi ! \n Below I send you ";

    NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"m1891@gmail.com"];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MV" ofType:@"pdf"]; NSData *myData
= [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: path];

    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
    [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
    [mc addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"MV.pdf"];

    [mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

    [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: Great answer! This is it!

Comment: One should also implement the delegate [didFinishWithResult](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10992845/426227).